# How to release memory or remove temp files created by http.ParseMultipartForm?

Tags: go

I'm using `http.ParseMultipartForm` to handle file uploads at my webapp.
Documentation says:

> ParseMultipartForm parses a request body as multipart/form-data. The whole request body is parsed and up to a total of maxMemory bytes of its file parts are stored in memory, with the remainder stored on disk in temporary files. ParseMultipartForm calls ParseForm if necessary. After one call to ParseMultipartForm, subsequent calls have no effect.

When the memory and/or temporary file will be deleted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything is freed after the request is complete.

The memory buffers will be available for garbage collection, and any temporary files will be removed by the call to `MultipartForm.RemoveAll()` at the end of the request.

Comment: I'm passing the `multipart.File` around with struct and by definition the GC will not clear at end of request, right?

Comment: @dvd: If you have a reference to the multipart.File, then it can't be collected. Once there are no more references it's eligible for collection. That's the point of garbage collection

Comment: Remember to `Close()` any file before calling `RemoveAll()` or files will keep floating at your temp directory.

Comment: can I just rename those temp files to another directory??

Comment: I experimented on Win10 with `ParseMultipartForm()` not doing `RemoveAll()`. All the files that I uploaded were stored as temporary files named `multipart-*.*` in C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Local\Temp\. Finally, I had to delete them manually.